# problem in recording video in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

i am using Ubuntu 14.04 which is able to pick up webcam by installing Guvcview. But it records only sound when i try to record video. is there any problem in webcam or i need to use commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering the resolution of your video camera, with my Logitech C170, this is the way it works with Cheese.